# File type Input does not point to right folder on IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please help me this issue for IE9

When I choose file to upload, then choose again, it points to fakepath in IE9 ??

Pls see my attached image for more details:
[image]

[image]

[image]

I mean, I choose file to upload, then reset it by $("file").val(" "), and choose file again ( point to fakepath ! ) but I browse to  the new file and choose it 
-> no file to display on input file type

You can check in this page (IE9)
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_accept

Comment: I can't replicate that in IE9 (or IE11, but it looks like a bug so I'd've hoped they would have fixed it). Please quote a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving "fakepath" to your JavaScript code is normal, not specific to IE9, and there's nothing you can do about it. You're not allowed to know where the file is really coming from, the path really is fake. But if you upload it, it will upload okay, and if you read it via the File API (on browsers that support it, so not IE9), you'll successfully read it.

Defaulting to it if you re-select the file input sounds like an IE9 bug (though I can't replicate it in IE9). I doubt there's anything you can do about that, either, other than suggesting to users that they update to something more up-to-date.

Comment: But when I reset this file input like this $("file").val(" "), and upload again, it does not display new file upload :(

Comment: @Jerry: I don't know what you mean by "does not display new file upload".

Comment: I mean, I choose file to upload, then reset it by $("file").val(" "), and choose file again ( point to fakepath ! ) but I browse to  the new file and choose it -> no file to display on input file type

Comment: You can check it in this page : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_accept

Hope that you have idea. Thank you

Comment: @Jerry: You're not allowed to set the value of a file input at all. If you want to clear it, reset the form it's in, or remove it and create a new file input. (And I still can't replicate what you describe.)

Comment: Yes, I will try it. Thank you very much :)